# Unable to load a page using Hound in Elixir

Tags: elixir, headless-browser, hound

I'm trying to request a page and inspect it but I get:

```
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(Hound.SessionServer, {:change_session0.100.0>, :default, []}, 60000)
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
 ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :econnrefused}

            (hound) lib/hound/session_server.ex:78: Hound.SessionServer.hall/3
```

My code:

```
Hound.start_session
Hound.Helpers.navigate_to("http://example.com")
Hound.end_session
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: @mudasobwa, how is it non-existing?

Comment: Is a webdriver server running on your system as mentioned in Hound's README? https://github.com/HashNuke/hound/#setup https://github.com/HashNuke/hound/wiki/Starting-a-webdriver-server

Answer (score -1):

Right below your `defmodule` you will want to include the line `use Hound.Helpers`.

Then your code should look something like this:

```
Hound.start_session

navigate_to('www.website.com')

Hound.end_session
```